# How make android application Proxy Aware (Programmatically)?

Tags: android, proxy, burp

When I use any proxy like Burp or Owasp ZAP, I see that many applications follow the proxy path and some doesn't and they just flow data directly.

I want to know what code is used for this, so that I can choose my own application to be proxy aware or not.

Comment: Please add more details !

Comment: I only found this that might be helpful but which provides no reference/background context for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24417392/425997

Comment: Maybe one option you can do if you "own" the application codebase, is to add proxy support into the app explicitly? But that means the user/admin will have to enable the proxy from the app side rather than globally. In the event that the app by default is not able to use the global/wifi proxy. I think there may be some APIs from Android to set proxy: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Proxy

Comment: Ya this one looks like good resource. So instead of using networking like other apps, if we use sockets for networking with NO_PROXY setting, it will avoid system proxy settings.