# Local Server or Domain Chrome Mobile Debugging with Port Forwarding

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, usb-debugging

I'm trying to setup Chrome mobile debugging using an Android phone and a USB connection.

I have managed to get the device available in `chrome://inspect/#devices` and can inspect remote sites e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), etc.

However, I would like to test a local site/app running on a local server e.g. http://my-local-server, etc. I tried the port-forwarding feature, but I can only access localhost, not a local domain.

Am I able to do this without the somewhat [complicated Proxy/Wi-fi setup](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/#configure_proxy_settings_on_your_device)?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution.

Before you attempt this, [setup port forwarding for Chrome mobile debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/#port-forwarding) and keep track of the ports. Let's call them:

- Port 1: the listening port on the device e.g. 6040
- Port 2: the listening port on the local machine e.g. 8090

#### Steps:

1. Install [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org) (if you don't have it)
2. Create a file called `proxy.js` in a directory of your choice
3. Copy the contents of [the code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andris9/8093905/raw/c4e373d158edbc5fbcf430dea3eb387c68880d5e/change_origin_proxy.js) from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/andris9/8093905#file-change_origin_proxy-js) and paste into `proxy.js`
4. Run the following command in the terminal from said directory:

```
PORT_LISTEN=8090 PORT_TARGET=80 HOST_TARGET="my-local-server" HOST_ORIGIN="my-local-server" node proxy.js
```

What's happening is as follows:

- Chrome has already setup a port-forwarding setup from your device to `localhost:8090`
- By running the code above, you have created a proxy server to listen on port 8090 and forward to your local server at port 80. The `HOST_ORIGIN` indicates to the web server who the request is for i.e. `my-local-server`

```
localhost:6040 --> localhost:8090 --> my-local-server:80
```

On your device, you should now be able to visit `http://localhost:6040` and see your local server/domain site.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is possible with [Drony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandrob.drony&hl=pt&gl=US). Instructions to download and first configuration are in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75214767/13720928.

Follow further directions here:

1. Select the network, then select `Filter default value -> Direct all` to direct all connections to where the're supposed to be requested
   [image]
2. Add a filter rule. Type in your localhost custom name, such as `mylocalsite.net`.
   [image]
3. Select `Action -> Allow` and click on save
   [image]
4. In `Log` tab turn on Drony

Enjoy browsing while developing your app! Or develop your app while accessing both localhost and another api service.